# Custom Scaler function doubling length (rows) of pandas dataframe in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

I am not sure if this is a pandas specific question but I am pretty sure it has something to do with the cat function in this code. I am relatively new to coding so my experience is pretty limited.

I am trying to create a class that will allow me to select the columns of the data that I want to scale. The custom function is based on the Standard Scaler model from skLearn. Whenever I try and split my data into training and test sets, I get an error that says the lengths of the dataframes do not match. When I check the size of the dataframes before the scaling they are the same length, however, after they are scaled the inputs are double the length.

I am not sure how to include the dataset since it is from a csv file, but it has an index that is a unique ID for each record and four columns:

1. gender (1 or 2)
2. age
3. race (1-7 discrete)
4. options (0-7 discrete)

The dataset has about 6000 records in it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#### Creates binary targets and then removes 'options' column to eliminate multicolinearity
targets = np.where(df['options'] > 0, 1, 0)
df['targets'] = targets
df_targets = df.drop([options'], axis=1)

#### Creating Inputs
df_inputs = df_targets.iloc[:,:-1]

#### Scaling Inputs (Custom)
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

class CustomScaler(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, columns, copy=True, with_mean=True, with_std=True):
        self.scaler = StandardScaler(copy,with_mean,with_std)
        self.columns = columns
        self.mean_ = None
        self.var_ = None

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        self.scaler.fit(X[self.columns], y)
        self.mean_ = np.mean(X[self.columns])
        self.var_ = np.var(X[self.columns])
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None, copy=None):
        init_col_order = X.columns
        X_scaled = pd.DataFrame(self.scaler.transform(X[self.columns]), columns = self.columns)
        X_not_scaled = X.loc[:,~X.columns.isin(self.columns)]
        return pd.concat([X_not_scaled, X_scaled], axis = 1)[init_col_order]

columns_to_omit = ['gender','race']
columns_to_scale = [x for x in df_inputs.columns.values if x not in columns_to_omit]

input_scaler = CustomScaler(columns_to_scale)

input_scaler.fit(df_inputs)

scaled_inputs = input_scaler.transform(df_inputs)

#### Splitting the Data
train_inputs, test_inputs, train_targets, test_targets = train_test_split(scaled_inputs, targets, train_size = 0.8, random_state = 144)
```

Here is the error that I get:

> ..............in 
> train_inputs, test_inputs, train_targets, test_targets = train_test_split(scaled_inputs, targets, train_size = 0.8,
> random_state = 42)   File
> "/home/sid/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py",
> line 2118, in train_test_split
> arrays = indexable(*arrays)   File "/home/sid/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py",
> line 248, in indexable
> check_consistent_length(*result)   File "/home/sid/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py",
> line 212, in check_consistent_length
> " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths]) ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [12302, 6151]

Answer (score 0):

Is the first line written correctly?

```
targets = np.where(df['options'] > 0, 1, 0)
```

I think there should be something else instead of 1.

Comment: Yes it is correct. I am trying to create a column that is basically a bunch of yes or no values based on the values from the options column. I want my regression to be able to predict whether or not a positive or negative option will occur (positive and negative being subjective in this case) based on an individuals race, gender and age. It could easily be changed to a continuous variable between 0 and 1 to become more specific.